# Creating a parametric plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi i'm new to python I've been trying to recreate a parametric plot in python. the original was mathematica this is what i have so far. I don' think ill have a problem formatting the graph if i follow the proper syntax. The problem that i'm having is how to get it to plot. This is what the plot should look like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKVNC.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

gamma_0 = 72.8
temp = 293.15

gamma[x_2]= gamma_0 -0.0187 * temp * math.log(1+628.14*55.556* x_2)

plt.plt(gamma[x_2])

plt.xlabel('Log_10x_2')
plt.ylabel('gamma (erg cm^2)')
```

Comment: well for one you can't use gamma[x_2] as a variable name because of the square brackets, unless x_2 is a number and you're storing the result in gamma's x_2-th element....second it's plt.plot, third x_2 is not defined in the log part and in the end this only gives you one value anyways

Comment: Thanks, i changed it to parentheses. Im not sure how they defined defined it in the Mathmatica plot

Answer (score 0):

This is what i got from your limited question. The Problem is In Function Calling with plt

The line :

```
plt.plt(gamma[x_2])
```

must be like

```
plt.plot(gamma[x_2])
```

Comment: What do you need me to expand on